# Inserting/Retrieve a associated entity via WebApi?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebAPI and EF world. I am still not too sure of how associated entities work.

Say if I want to retrieve and return a `Car` along with it's associated entity `Driver`, If I simply do `return dbContext.Cars`, will `Drivers` be included in the response as well?

If I am passing in `Cars` entity with a nested `Driver` object into WebAPI via JSON, will asp.net automatically interpret it as two associated objects and insert into my database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1**
If you wish to include associated Drivers you will have to return

```
return dbContext.Cars.Include(c => c.Drivers);
```

**2**
Yes, once your JSON properties are correctly named